# Need to find current connections in mysql media server log table

Tags: mysql

I have a media server logging to a mysql database and it records a seperate row for each connect, play, stop, disconnect event. What I would like to do is find connect events that do not have a related disconnect event or play events that do not have a related stop event.

```
date          time        category    event      clientId    stream    streamId
===============================================================================
2010-04-21    10:30:00    session     connect    1          
2010-04-21    10:30:05    stream      start      1           stream1    1
2010-04-21    10:35:00    stream      stop       1           stream1    1
2010-04-21    10:35:00    session     disconnect 1           
2010-04-21    10:35:00    session     connect    2           
2010-04-21    10:35:05    stream      start      2           stream2    1
2010-04-21    10:35:08    session     connect    3           
2010-04-21    10:35:13    stream      start      3           stream1    1
2010-04-21    10:37:05    stream      stop       2           stream2    1
2010-04-21    10:37:10    stream      start      2           stream1    2
```

I would like to be able to get a total of current sessions and in a seperate query, a total of current streams being played.

Thanks,

Roger.

Comment: This could be difficult without a unique session id in the data set.  Presumably clientId with value 1 could appear many times historically, and could also have many sessions open at the same time.

Comment: Hi Martin,

The client id is unique to each session so in effect, it is the session id.  In the real data, it is a 10 digit random number that shouldn't be repeated unless the server is restarted.

Comment: Also, I have just added the streamId column.  this always starts at 1 for a stream that is played in a session.  each subsequent stream in the session increments the streamId.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using a compound select statement.

```
select * from (select *, (select true from statslog as t1 where t1.clientId = statslog.clientId and t1.event = 'disconnect') as `disconnected`
from statslog where statslog.category = 'session' and statslog.event = 'connect') as t2 where isnull(t2.disconnected);
```